# Memory leak in C++ (Valgrind)

Tags: c++, stack, valgrind

I implement the stack with a minimum. In this program, I get an error from valgrind. Something is wrong with the push() and main() functions. When I add delete st; to the push() function, I get even more errors. I check it through valgrind ./a.out. Sorry for the long code. I also wrote the rest of the functions for stack. But there is no error in them, I left those in the code where there may be an error.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct Stack {
  int data;
  int min;
  Stack* next;
};

void Push(Stack** top, int n) {
  Stack* st = new Stack();
  st->data = n;
  if (*top == NULL) {
    *top = st;
    (**top).min = n;
  } else {
    st->min = ((n <= (**top).min) ? n : (**top).min);
    st->next = *top;
    *top = st;
  }
  std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
}

void Pop(Stack** top) {
  if (*top != NULL) {
    std::cout << (**top).data << std::endl;
    *top = (*top)->next;
  } else {
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  Stack* top = nullptr;
  int m;
  std::cin >> m;
  std::string str;
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    std::cin >> str;
    if (str == "push") {
      int value;
      std::cin >> value;
      Push(&top, value);
    }
    if (str == "pop") {
      Pop(&top);
    }
  }
  delete top;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't `Push` and `Pop` member functions of `Stack`?  Why did you create a `Stack` class that has half of the functions related to stacks outside of the class (poor encapsulation)?  Also, the way you avoid memory leaks is to not write code that introduces them.  `std::stack<int>` is a stack class that takes integers and has no memory leaks.

Comment: I'm new to C++ programming. I used to write in Python. Please do not judge strictly. Yes, it may be a bad encapsulation, but I was asked to write it that way. I was asked to implement all the functions myself.

Comment: The `next` member variable of `Stack` is uninitialized when `*top == NULL`.  The idiomatic way to initialize a new instance of an object in C++ is to define a constructor, that way instantiation and initialization are done together.

Comment: Then you are basically learning `C`, not `C++`.  Ask for a refund.  In this day and age of C++, code shouldn't look like what you have been tasked to write.

Comment: There's a `new` in `Push`, so there should most likely be a `delete` in `Pop`.

Comment: This is the beginning of learning C++. We will switch to classes soon, but we were told that in order to understand classes, we first need to figure out what the structure is. Maybe those who program at an advanced level notice a lot of errors in my code. I understand that and thank you for your comments.

Comment: *This is the beginning of learning C++.* -- Beginners shouldn't be given code like this.  It is bad code, and you learn nothing except frustration -- double pointers, raw calls to `new`, etc..  It's teachers like the one you have that makes students drop C++ and go to JavaScript, Python, or some other language., where they actually learn to write useful programs without the frustration.

Comment: As to your code, your `main` function should be much simpler: `int main() { Stack** top = nullptr; Push(&top, 10); Pop(&top); }` -- Nothing more than that.  Then if that gives an error, you debug it.  If it doesn't work for one value, it isn't going to work for `m` values.

Comment: OK. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just `delete top`, you destruct it (in your case it's nothing, but you can distract yourself for reading about [destructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) if interested) and free the dynamic memory allocated for `top`. However, you actually want to also `delete` `top->next`, `top->next->next` (if present) etc. A hotfix:

```
while (top) { // same as "while (top != nullptr) {"
    Stack* next = top->next; // we can't use `top` after we `delete` it, save `next` beforehand
    delete top;
    top = next;
}
```

Now, about more general things. The course teaches you some really old C++ (almost just plain C; even C here is bad though). At the very least, your whole `Push()` can be replaced (thanks to [lvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) (`Type&`), [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)) with:

```
void push(Stack*& top, int n) {
    top = new Stack{n, std::min(n, top ? top->min : n), top};
    std::cout << "ok\n";
}
```

> I'm new to C++ programming. I used to write in Python

Good job. Sadly, such teaching shows C++ as something too old and horrifying.

## Edit

> here's a new in Push, so there should most likely be a delete in Pop

That's right (thanks to @molbdnilo). You should `delete` `pop`ped elements instead of just leaking them.